Sorting the collection of catalog products by attribute and its specific parameter Magento 2.4.6
I have a custom attribute named "Promotion" (ID: 489, code: "special_attributes") which includes four options: Promo, Sale, etc. I need to sort the catalog product collection by the "Sale" option, similar to how products are sorted by price. For instance, if the current category contains 15 products marked as "Sale," the first page should display 12 of these products (according to the pagination settings), and the remaining three should appear at the top of the next page.
Previously, I attempted to implement this sorting from a different part of the code, but it only sorted the products on the current pagination page, not the entire collection.
I tried writing a plugin for the Layer class, but it didn't work. Perhaps this isn't the right class for this task. Any guidance on where and how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.
/**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $result
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     */
    public function afterPrepareProductCollection($subject, $result, $collection)
    {
        if ($this->request->getFullActionName() !== 'catalog_category_view') {
            return;
        }

        $collection->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $this->joinAttribute('special_atributes', $collection);
        $this->sortCollectionByPromotionalAction($collection);

        return $this;
    }

    private function joinAttribute($attributeCode, $collection)
    {
        $fromPart = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
        if (array_key_exists($attributeCode, $fromPart)) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            $attribute = $this->attrRepository->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $attributeCode);

            if (!$attribute) {
                return false;
            }

            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                [$attributeCode => $attribute->getBackendTable()],
                "e.entity_id = {$attributeCode}.entity_id AND {$attributeCode}.attribute_id = {$attribute->getAttributeId()}",
                []
            );

            return true;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return void
     */
    private function sortCollectionByPromotionalAction($collection)
    {
        $alias = 'is_actual_promotional_order';

        $expression = new \Zend_Db_Expr(
            "CASE
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET('5008', special_atributes.value) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END"
        );

        $collection->getSelect()->columns([
            $alias => $expression
        ]);

        $collection->getSelect()->order([
            "$alias DESC",
            "e.created_at DESC"
        ]);
    }

Need to Sorting the collection of catalog products by attribute and its specific parameter
